# Kawamata coverings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I’m looking at a proof in Lazarsfeld, [Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-18808-4).  It’s about Kawamata coverings (4.1.12).  I don’t understand the need to first use a Bloch–Gieseker covering.  Wouldn’t a cyclic covering be sufficient?

Comment: Questions are usually better received if self contained, so it would help if you could provide context allowing the question to be answered even by someone who doesn't have the book.

Comment: I’m sorry.  I don’t have LaTex.  Given a smooth divisor D, first use a Bloch-Gieseker covering to get A with the pullback of D linearly equivalent to mA.  Then use a cyclic covering to get D’ with mD’ the pullback of D.  These processes seem redundant.

Comment: The construction of a cyclic cover depends on a choice of $m$-th root of $\mathcal O_X(D)$. So you first need to create the line bundle that in Proposition 4.1.6 is called $L$, starting only from $L^{\otimes m} = \mathcal O_X(D)$.

Comment: His first step constructs a divisor whose mth power is the pullback.  But the conclusion of the proposition is that such an mth power exists.  I still don’t see why the proof didn’t end there.

Comment: I think $D'_i$ is supposed to be a smooth *effective* divisor, which is what the second step (cyclic covers) achieves. Moreover, the proposition asks for equality as divisors, not divisor classes up to linear equivalence (i.e. line bundles).

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for your insight.